# Умножение ключа массива на значению. PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив:

```php
$arr = array(3=>5, 7=>2, 35=>9, 21=>1,);
```

Как можно умножить ключ на значению?
Например: `3*5=15`

Через `foreach` не смог сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в цикл foreach можно получать и ключ, и значение

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $res[] = $k*$v;
}
```

и смотрим результат